# Си возврат функцией результата

Tags: android, c, char, native

Программирую на Android Ndk C. Нужно вызвать функцию. которая что-то делает, и после вернуть результат.

```
char test(){
    char m[4];
    char m2[3] = "123";
    strncpy(m,&m2[0],3);
    m[4] = 0;
    return m;
}
```

Лог выводит все нормально, а при возврате вылетает. Почитал, локальная переменная уничтожается после работы функции. Как вернуть результат?

Comment: Никакой зависимости от "уничтожения локальной переменной" в этом коде нет.

Comment: Что такое `return m`, если функция должна возвращать просто `char`?

Comment: @ AnT нужно возвратить строку собранную

Comment: если возвратить char* то к строке дописывается хлам всякий

Comment: Если возвратить `char *`, то будет именно "уничтожение локальной переменной". Вы занимаетесь какими-то бессмысленными модификациями бессмысленного кода. Вопрос бессмыслен, пока вы детально не объясните, что же вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Вот что нужно http://studassistent.ru/c/skopirovat-v-stroku-neskolko-simvolov-drugoy-stroki-nachinaya-s-nekotoroy-pozicii-c-si толькооформить как функцию которая возвратит данные точной длины, а не данные+ хлам

Answer (score 0):

Вылетает при возврате из-за `ch[2] = 0;`. Вы объявили массив `ch` с размером `2`, т.е. доступные индексы массива - это `ch[0]` и `ch[1]`. С чего вы взяли, что можно лезть в `ch[2]`? Вылет за пределы массива - неопределенное поведение.

Также стоит заметить, что у вас в `c` нет "строки" - в `c` размера `1` не помещается нулевой терминатор.

Comment: Опечатался массив там len.Ошибка не в этом 2 для примера.

Comment: @Ivan: Все равно `ch[2]` - за пределами массива.

Comment: как нужно тогда.делал по примеру

Comment: @Ivan: "Как нужно" зависит от того, "что нужно сделать". Из вашего кода это совершенно не понятно. Зачем здесь вообще `strncpy`???

Comment: скопировать в ch пустой строку из c

Comment: Ivan: Просто `char ch[2]; char c[] = "1"; strcpy(ch, c);`

Comment: Не так сказал.c длинная строка нужно в ch скопировать 5 симвролов начиная например с 3

Comment: через malloc четко выделил память 20 символов,записал 20 результат 30.Пол дня разбираюсь

Comment: @Ivan: Ну тогда все правильно, только косяки с размерами и индексами исправить надо.

Comment: через малок проблемы потому что char* а тут char

Comment: @ AnT Исправил код посмотрите

Comment: @Ivan: У вас все те же ошибки! Сколько можно повторять: если массив объявлен как `char m[4]`, то к `m[4]` доступаться нельзя - это за пределами массива.

Comment: так я по примеру сделал там так и делают

Comment: @Ivan: Это где вы нашли такой пример?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам надо возвращать `char*`. Мусор у вас там потому что переменная `m` находится на стеке, поэтому при выходе из функции там может оказаться что угодно. Либо передавайте в функцию буфер в котором будет сформирована новая строка, либо создавайте этот буфер в функции с помощью `new/malloc`.

```
m[4] = 0;
```

так же является ошибкой так как у вас массив всего на 4 элемента, последний индекс там `3`.